# When they say carbyn is an html5 based OS, do they mean that carbyn is a javascript based OS?

Tags: javascript, html, operating-system

More specifically, How is it possible to create an os with a markup language? Or is this really a misnomer and the OS itself is built on top of JavaScript?

I don't wish for any sort of markup for the actual os, but it just seems like an impossible task without even the most basic control flow, like if statements/for loops or jumps.

If anyone can show me an If in Html5, I will definitely be satisfied, or just a they do that stuff with javascript works as well.

http://www.carbyn.com/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNAuB5JWfoE

Comment: HTML 5 isn't just a markup language. It defines a large number of APIs (usually interacted with via JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a web application, that itself is a platform for HTML5 (mostly javscript) web applications. It provides a set of APIs that javascript "applications" can implement to run on their platform and "multitask" and communicate amongst each other.

To help visualize, you can think of how facebook has apps that developers can make. That's not a perfect comparison, but it can kind of help you get in the right frame of mind. Carbyn seems MUCH more open than facebook is in terms of apps, and of course that's the whole point.

That's my thoughts after reading what's available and watching the video, hope it helps!

Comment: That makes complete sense to me for Facebook, written in PHP. However I have no idea how you would even start to implement processes / threads or anything really in a Markup Language. Even as simple as how do you add two arbitrary (8 bit) int's using only html5?

Comment: HTML5 refers to a set of technologies, most of which is a set of new Javascript APIs. So think in terms of Javascript, not HTML. I see how that would be misleading.